# Two different buttons performing segue to same view controller but want to disable user interaction for segue through one button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I am performing segue to same view controller from two different buttons on same screen and hence using same segue identifier. Say buttons are B1 and B2. So when when I perform segue from segue from B1, I want destination view controller to have user interaction disabled but when when I segue from B2, I want destination view controller to to be clickable and its text fields to be editable.  Please help me implement it.   Here...consider B2 to be partialpressed and B1 to be toplbl and please help me implement it using this code so suggest me changes i can make here.

```
@IBAction func partialPressed(sender: UIButton)
{
    let i = self.getIndex(sender.tag)
    let j = self.getSection(sender.tag)
    let indexarr = ["index":i, "section":j]

    if getSection(sender.tag) == 0
    {

    let arr = getArray(sender.tag)
    performSegueWithIdentifier("partialSupplement", sender: arr)

    }
    else if getSection(sender.tag) == 1
    {
        let arr = getArray(sender.tag)
        performSegueWithIdentifier("PartialPopup", sender: arr)




    }

    else if getSection(sender.tag) == 2
    {
        let arr = getArray(sender.tag)
        performSegueWithIdentifier("FoodLifestyle", sender: arr)



    else if getSection(sender.tag) == 3
    {
        let arr = getArray(sender.tag)
        performSegueWithIdentifier("Food", sender: arr)


    else if getSection(sender.tag) == 4
    {
        let arr = getArray(sender.tag)
        performSegueWithIdentifier("Others", sender: arr)
      task.resume()
    }

}
```

@IBAction func toplbl(sender: UIButton){

```
    let i = self.getIndex(sender.tag)
    let j = self.getSection(sender.tag)
    let indexarr = ["index":i, "section":j]

    if getSection(sender.tag) == 0
    {
              task.resume()

        let arr1 = getArray(sender.tag)
        performSegueWithIdentifier("partialSupplement", sender: arr1)





    }
    else if getSection(sender.tag) == 1
    {
        let arr1 = getArray(sender.tag)
        performSegueWithIdentifier("PartialPopup", sender: arr1)


    }

    else if getSection(sender.tag) == 2
    {
        let arr1 = getArray(sender.tag)
        performSegueWithIdentifier("FoodLifestyle", sender: arr1)

              task.resume()
    }

    else if getSection(sender.tag) == 3
    {
        let arr1 = getArray(sender.tag)
        performSegueWithIdentifier("Food", sender: arr1)
          task.resume()
    }

    else if getSection(sender.tag) == 4
    {
        let arr1 = getArray(sender.tag)
        performSegueWithIdentifier("Others", sender: arr1)
                 task.resume()
    }

}
```

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

```
    if segue.identifier == "menuviewcontroller"
    {
        let menuTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! MenuViewcontroller
        menuTableViewController.transitioningDelegate = menuTransitionManager
        menuTransitionManager.delegate = self

       // menuTableViewController.customchildcelldataarray = self.customchildcelldataarray

    }
    if segue.identifier == "PartialPopup"
    {
        let popupViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! PatialViewController
        popupViewController.arr = sender as! CustomcomingupDataWorkOut
        //popupViewController.timings_id = popupViewController.arr.timings_id
        //menuTransitionManager.delegate = self
        // menuTableViewController.customchildcelldataarray = self.customchildcelldataarray

    }
    if segue.identifier == "partialSupplement"
    {
        let popupViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! PartialSupplementViewController
        var arr = sender as! CustomcomingUpDataSupplements
        popupViewController.lifestyletype = arr.supplementName
        popupViewController.lifestyleItem = arr.amount + arr.unit
        popupViewController.lifestyleQuantity = arr.dosage_main_name
        popupViewController.timings_id = arr.timings_id



        //popupViewController.arr = sender as! CustomcomingUpDataSupplements
        //popupViewController.timings_id = popupViewController.arr.timings_id
        //menuTransitionManager.delegate = self
        // menuTableViewController.customchildcelldataarray = self.customchildcelldataarray

    }

    if segue.identifier == "FoodLifestyle"
    {
        let popupViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! partialFoodViewController
        var arr = sender as! CustomcomingUpDataLifeStyle
        popupViewController.lifestyletype = arr.lifestyle_name
        popupViewController.lifestyleItem = arr.time + " minutes"
        popupViewController.lifestyleQuantity = "Time"
        popupViewController.timings_id = arr.timings_id


        //popupViewController.arr = sender as! CustomcomingupDataWorkOut
        //menuTransitionManager.delegate = self
        // menuTableViewController.customchildcelldataarray = self.customchildcelldataarray

    }
    if segue.identifier == "Food"
    {
        let popupViewController1 = segue.destinationViewController as! FoodViewController
        var arr = sender as! CustomcominUpDataFood
        print(arr)
        popupViewController1.type = arr.food_name
        popupViewController1.Item = arr.time
        popupViewController1.Quantity = " Amount"
        popupViewController1.timings_id = arr.timings_id


        //popupViewController.arr = sender as! CustomcomingupDataWorkOut
        //menuTransitionManager.delegate = self
        // menuTableViewController.customchildcelldataarray = self.customchildcelldataarray

    }
    //Others
    if segue.identifier == "Others"
    {
        let popupViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! PartialOthersViewController
        var arr = sender as! CustomcominUpDataOthers
        popupViewController.lifestyletype = arr.others_name
        popupViewController.lifestyleItem = arr.time + " minutes"
        popupViewController.lifestyleQuantity = "Completion"
        popupViewController.timings_id = arr.timings_id
        //popupViewController.arr = sender as! CustomcomingupDataWorkOut
        //menuTransitionManager.delegate = self
        // menuTableViewController.customchildcelldataarray = self.customchildcelldataarray

    }

}
```

Comment: Check the sender in `prepareForSegue` and set a property on the destination view controller

Comment: @Paulw11 ..can you give me the complete function please and do I need to pass extra object for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out an easy way to do it. We can declare one global or local boolean variable for partialpressed button we can set it to true and for toplbl button we can set it to false and then we have 2 ways to disable user interaction :

1. if bool is global: go to destination view controller and inside view did load check for if bool == false then set self.view.userinteraction = false
2. if bool is local variable: go to prpareforsegue inside initial view controller and check for if bool == false then set segue.destinationviewcontroller.view.userinteraction = false

Answer (score 1):

Use [`prepareForSegue:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepareforsegue?language=objc) method. iOS will pass you the button as a `sender` parameter, and also make the destination view controller available as part of `UIStoryboardSegue` parameter.

Check `sender` to see if it is `B1` or `B2`. When the sender is `B2`, disable user interaction in segue's destination controller:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "MySegue" {
        let enableInteration = (sender != button2)
        segue.destinationViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = enableInteration
    }
}
```

Comment: you are checking this inside destination view controller or initial view controller i.e from view controller where you are performing segue?

Comment: @Rouny This happens in the "from" controller.

Comment: can you suggest me change is my code....the code i have pasted in post.

Comment: @Rouny The two lines inside the `if` go inside the `if` in your `prepareForSegue` code. `(sender != button2)` needs to change to match your decision making on whether `sender` is button `B2` or not.

Comment: actually that button have been linked as function in this view controller so i am not able to use it as conditional object inside (if sender = )

Comment: @Rouny Use its `tag` then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one key, and change the value of that key before calling segue. And according to that key change the interaction of buttons/textfields etc. This is a workaround, maybe you will get better answer than this.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an Int, like so:

```
var buttonIndex = 0

@IBAction func partialPressed(sender: UIButton){

buttonIndex = 1
performSegueWithIdentifier("PartialPopup", sender: sender)

}

@IBAction func toplbl(sender: UIButton){

buttonIndex = 2
performSegueWithIdentifier("PartialPopup", sender: sender)

}
```

Then:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

destVC == segue.destination
destVC.buttonIndex = self.buttonIndex

}
```

And then, in destVC:

```
var buttonIndex = 0

switch buttonIndex{

case 1:
// Do whatever magic is desired if partialPressed was tapped

case 2:
// Do whatever magic is desired if toplbl was tapped

default:
break
}
```